# Cannot compile basic rust file

Tags: macos, rust

- OS: macOS Mojave 10.14.4 x86_64
- LLVM version: 8.0
- xcode-select version: 2354
- rustc 1.34.1

When run: `rustc main.rs`

```
error: linking with `cc` failed: exit code: 1
  |
  = note: "cc" "-m64" "-L" "/Users/abhay/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/x86_64-apple-darwin/lib" "main.main.7rcbfp3g-cgu.0.rcgu.o" "main.main.7rcbfp3g-cgu.1.rcgu.o" "main.main.7rcbfp3g-cgu.2.rcgu.o" "main.main.7rcbfp3g-cgu.3.rcgu.o" "main.main.7rcbfp3g-cgu.4.rcgu.o" "main.main.7rcbfp3g-cgu.5.rcgu.o" "-o" "main" "main.4s37gsrti678ik8u.rcgu.o" "-Wl,-dead_strip" "-nodefaultlibs" "-L" "/Users/abhay/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/x86_64-apple-darwin/lib" "/Users/abhay/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/libstd-69468557cf2e6e61.rlib" "/Users/abhay/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/libpanic_unwind-9c46cbe4b20f76c9.rlib" "/Users/abhay/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/libbacktrace_sys-1bab212c0168b306.rlib" "/Users/abhay/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/libunwind-ccbdb02fb3eef923.rlib" "/Users/abhay/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/librustc_demangle-e705bf8976fe8243.rlib" "/Users/abhay/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/liblibc-85176bbe7f63adc0.rlib" "/Users/abhay/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/liballoc-80e2cac000a11404.rlib" "/Users/abhay/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/librustc_std_workspace_core-1c0ce4c4b6e07a27.rlib" "/Users/abhay/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/libcore-f81ce6e54e0bbe9c.rlib" "/Users/abhay/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/libcompiler_builtins-d2154badfa119bbc.rlib" "-lSystem" "-lresolv" "-lc" "-lm"
  = note: ld: malformed file
          /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/lib/libm.tbd:4:18: error: unknown enumerated scalar
          platform:        zippered
                           ^~~~~~~~
           file '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/lib/libm.tbd'
          clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: https://forum.qt.io/topic/101278/build-make-error-ld-malformed-file-unknown-enumerated-scalar-platform-zippered/4?

Comment: @hellow Is there a way to comment on edit reviews? ...anyway, why is the "macos" tag not appropriate for this question? I think "macos" defines the context of it, maybe even more than the "rustc" tag.

Comment: @chpio IMHO the macOS tag is not appropiate here, because this question is not related to the macOS API or macOS-specific behavior (as described in the tag info). But rather in the linker used on macOS (e.g. the SDK). But it's a peer review, if two people think it's okay, then it's okay :)

Answer (score 1):

**Reference:** [Solution taken from](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/31159#issuecomment-481910401)

FYI, If you want to stay on xcode 9.4.1, you can do the following:

If you are running on Mojave, you will need to install the MacOS headers in the base system:

`sudo installer -pkg /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg -target /`